# Python: how to remove values from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have this array in my code however I need to remove the rows that contain zeros (in this case the third row and the fourth). I have tried some options but all without success, can someone suggest something for me to solve this problem?

I leave below the array:

```
print(AA)
array([[2.40258090e+01, 5.46388441e+00],
       [2.37367092e+01, 1.63425169e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 1.56246202e-01],
       [1.68035590e+01, 0.00000000e+00],
       [1.06032437e+01, 6.41505749e+00]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a row in a numpy array which contains a zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397805/how-do-i-delete-a-row-in-a-numpy-array-which-contains-a-zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So python doesn't have built-in support for arrays.  Please use a list.

So to answer your question, let's create a list:

```
lst =   [[2.40258090e+01, 5.46388441e+00],
        [2.37367092e+01, 1.63425169e+02],
        [0.00000000e+00, 1.56246202e-01],
        [1.68035590e+01, 0.00000000e+00],
        [1.06032437e+01, 6.41505749e+00]]

# Now we filter
filtered_lst = [elem for elem in lst if 0 not in elem]
print(filtered_lst)
```

output:

```
[[24.025809, 5.46388441], [23.7367092, 163.425169], [10.6032437, 6.41505749]]
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

#### Value Based:

To filter an array by value, boolean masking can be used as:

```
a[(a[:,0] != 0) & (a[:,1] != 0)]
```

This filters array `a` to keep only rows where values in columns `0` *and* `1` are not zero; using the bitwise `&` operator.

#### Index Based:

With a numpy array, using `np.delete` will do the trick, as:

```
np.delete(a, [2,3], axis=0)
```

where `a` is the array.

Remember, indexes are zero-based, so the third and fourth rows (`axis=0`) are indexed as `[2,3]`.

[Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)

Comment: It won't since you didn't `import numpy as np` before line 1.  Also, what tells you he's using numpy?

Comment: The syntax `array([[...]])` is a standard `numpy.ndarray`.  Additionally, the tags are a clear indication.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I guess you know numpy better than I do.

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the rows with 0s using basic Python

```
j=1
while j<len(a):
    for i in a[j]:
        if i == 0.0:
            a.remove(a[j])
            j-=1
    j+=1
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)